# Select data where not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, join

I try to make a query.

Three tables :

```
Table A
id
id_C
name
```

--

```
table B
id
id_A
id_X
```

--

```
table C
id
name
```

I would like to have all data in table A where B.is_A is null and B.id_X is null.

I try with this query

```
SELECT A.id, A.name
FROM A
INNER JOIN C ON (C.id = A.id_C)
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.id = B.id_A)
WHERE C.a_column = 3
AND B.id_A IS NULL
AND B.id_X IS NULL
```

This query return always 0.

How can I build a query that return the data I need?

**EDIT :**

I give some data :

I Have Three tables :

```
Table prestation
id  |  name     |   owner_id
1   |   Test    |   3
2   |   Toto    |   7
3   |   Tutu    |   2
4   |   Tata    |   2
5   |   Titi    |   4

Table owner
id      name
1   |   John
2   |   Alice
3   |   Bob


Table prestation_has_salaried
id  |   prestation_id   |   salaried_id
1   |   2               |   7
2   |   5               |   82
3   |   8               |   82
4   |   10              |   7
5   |   29              |   12
```

In my table prestation_has_salaried a couple of prestation_id and salaried_id is unique.

I Try to build a request that return from table prestation :

```
Prestation.id | Prestation.name
3             |   Tutu
4             |   Tata
```

Because I need prestation of owner Bob and because prestation_has_salaried has no prestation_id 3 and 4 (so prestation_has_salaried.prestation_id is null). 
I think I can build that with LEFT JOIN but I would like  prestation_has_salaried.salaried_id to be null too. 
Can I have that in the same query ? Or Maybe I need to pass by my PHP script ?

My query looks like :

```
SELECT prestation.id, prestation.name
FROM prestation
INNER JOIN owner ON (prestation.owner_id = owner.id)
LEFT JOIN prestation_has_salaried ON (prestation.id = prestation_has_salaried.prestation_id)
WHERE owner.id = 3
AND prestation_has_salaried.prestation_id IS NULL
AND prestation_has_salaried.salaried_id IS NULL
```

This query return 0 line.

I hope my explanation is clear...

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  First, how can you get rows in *A* if `B.id_a` is NULL -- there is no match?  Further, your question has no mention of `C`, yet your sample code does.  Please edit the question and provide sample data, desired results, and a clear statement of what you want to do.

Comment: some sample data is needed to understand the question.

Comment: show proper data sample and the expected result  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id
      ,A.name
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id_A = A.id OR B.id_A IS NULL;
```

Comment: HelloThanks for your reply. This query doesn't give the expected result. With this query I will have data that exist in table B. I would like to have data that doesn't exist in table B (B.id_A null and B.id_X null).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.